# D3.js selection does not have enter or exit

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, d3.js

So I have this

```
@currentlyDisplayedRows = @tbody.selectAll("tr").data(
    @collection.models.filter((d)=>
        if @filterFunc(toFilter,d)
        console.log "D"
        console.log d
        return d
)
```

I can't do that `.exit().remove()`, or `.enter().append('something')`. Why is that? Aren't I following the enter, update, exit pattern?

Answer (score 0):

That depends where you're adding the `.exit()` etc. They should appear after the closing parenthesis for `.data()`, i.e. at the very end of the block of code that you've posted. Another problem that may occur is that what you're passing to `.data()` is an empty array. In that case, calling `.exit()` etc should work, but won't do anything as the respective selections will be empty.